# Xcode: Create Developer ID Application Certificate

Tags: xcode, macos

So I'm logged into Xcode (one of the accounts) with my developer Apple ID. The problem is distributing the archive of my app (NOTE: I'm *not* distributing to the app store). I go to `Organizer > Distribute App > Developer ID > Export`
But my team (just me) isn't registered with the Developer ID Application certification. If I go to `Manage Certificates...` and click `add(+) > Developer ID Application`, I get a 
["Permissions Failure" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8VB5.png).

Other places I've looked to solve this problem have said that I need to add this certification using the *admin* account on the team. But in my account preferences, my role says *User*.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Developer Role. as per my picture 
[image]

Comment: So I need to be enrolled in the Apple Developer Program and pay $100 annually? Even if I'm just putting one .app file up for download on my own website for free??

Comment: @Raptor_Guy If you want to sign it with a Gatekeeper-accepted certificate, yes.

Comment: I second @GordonDavisson